# Flutter unable to build IOS archive

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, apple-developer, flutter-build

i am trying to build a IOS IPA for generic device, followed all the instructions, added signing certificates, team etc. but i am unable to build the product. any one please help me to resolve this issue.

here is my signing config. checked to automatically managed. added device in developer site.

[image]

> sent 435785657 bytes  received 92 bytes  58104766.53 bytes/sec
> total size is 435732165  speedup is 1.00
> Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "Apple Development: ********"
> /Users/Saif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bemaxobcrmqabgcgltuauohrwrje/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/myapp.app/Frameworks/App.framework/App: errSecInternalComponent
> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

[image]

i am just stuck on this error for about 3 days. tried each and every solution available on stackoverflow and apple developer stack.

Flutter : 2.0.1
Xcode : 11.2.1

Comment: did you try cleaning the build?

Comment: yes.... clean build, also manually deleted the folder 'DerivedData' from Xcode directory

Comment: try changing a to a dummy package name first and build it! ( it might the Bundle ID is not available issue )

Comment: you have full access to the account, did you do the signining report thingy with your local KeyChain to generate a cert file?

Comment: yes. generating certificate and uploaded to developer site too.

Comment: should i also delete the app from appstore connect that i created with same bundle id ?

Comment: no for now keep that! just do it with different bundle ID and try an ad-hoc build with it see if the same error comes

Comment: still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing any issue i think, the reason behind this i have an old version of xcode, i just update the xcode for newest version and than its all fine.

Comment: What's your new XCode version? I'm having a similar issue, but with 11.3

Comment: do check your macOS version specific xcode release from here https://xcodereleases.com.

in my case i have running macOS catalina and have older version of xcode, so i can only upgrade xcode to 12.4 which catalina could support as mentioned in xcoderelease, by manually downloading the file, everything went fine :D

Answer (score -1):

1. Run `flutter build ipa`
2. Once build is done. Open `Runner.xcarchive`
3. Open `Runner.xcarchive` with Xcode
4. It'll take you to the Distribute App page so you can upload the app

As per the docs:

https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/ios#create-a-build-archive-with-xcode